# Couldn't find comment without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models: comments and questions (questions belong to a comment). When trying to create a new question i get this error highlighting the first line of the controller. It worked fine up until recently so i dont know whats causing the error.

```
Couldn't find Comment without an ID
```

The controller looks like this:

```
def create
@comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
@question = @comment.questions.new(question_params)
end
```

The routes look like this:

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions 
end
```

After posting it redirects to '/questions' even if it specify a different path.

The questions form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@comment, Question.new] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :body, as: :text %>
<%= f.submit "Ask", :id => "button", class: "button5" %>
<% end %>
```

Parameters:

```
utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NJdlwZujnOpNfg6XZGyqFIPhIPSQ47GDWrUVJGkapR8=", "question"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "body"=>"hi"}, "commit"=>"Ask"}
```

Params:

```
params.require(:question).permit(:body, :title, :comment_id, :user_id, :image, :image_remote_url, :caption)
```

Comment: What are you trying to find in the create method? A parent?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Fairly new to rails - is the @comment line necessary?

Comment: I don't think it redirects. You seem to be posting to the wrong path. Please post your view code (the form). I think that's where the error is occurring.

Comment: Can you please also paste the parameters you get when you post to new question?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant the parameters you see in console?

Comment: Form seems to be OK, can you post the log entry that gets written after you post the form?

Comment: See edit. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The `@comment` in your form seems to be `nil`. Where does that come from?

Comment: You don't have :comment_id there. It should be like: `{utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NJdlwZujnOpNfg6XZGyqFIPhIPSQ47GDWrUVJGkapR8=", "question"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "body"=>"hi"}, "comment_id" => "1" "commit"=>"Ask"}` Which means, @comment in view is not available or being set.

Comment: Ah i see, any clue how would i go about fixing that? The route is 'comments/1/questions/new' so i am just wondering how @comment is not set.

Comment: Paste the `def new` method.

Comment: You have to add `@comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])` to `def new`.

Comment: OK added, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you reload `comments/1/questions/new` before trying again?

Comment: Yep reloaded it. Weird huh?

Comment: In which controller did you add that code?

Comment: Can you post the complete method where you have code: `params.require`?

Comment: @Mischa questions controller. Yep, edited.

Comment: is this the only line in that method? in `def question_params `?

Comment: Ok progress. I didnt add this line when i showed the form: <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>. I deleted it and now the error is 'undefined method `question' for #<Comment:0x00000106565b88>' highlighting the second line.

Comment: Ok i made questions plural but now it redirects to the specified path if question doesn't save.

Comment: So, you get the @comment now? And I think questions is plural in your question o.O

Comment: Yep comment_id shows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like params[:comment_id] is nil.

Comment: Any idea as to why this may be. Its weird because it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank check for the params or you can do `find_by_id` for comments so that it returns nil and for creating question you can do that only if you get comments

```
@comment = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id])
@question = @comment.question.new(question_params) if @comment.present?
```

Comment: This gives me an undefined method save for 'if @question.save'.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this line to find your comment:

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

I believe your problem is that your route is providing the id to the comment as the :id parameter.

Try running:

```
rake routes
```

and looking at the route to verify what kind of param it is returning to you.  You should see :id.

Comment: Hmm no same error. Rake routes gives me comment_id as well. For some reason it redirects to '/questions' if that is any clue.

Comment: Ah, right.  I didn't read the question very well.

You probably would get more help if you listed the uri and maybe the output of rake routes.